# Comma use in a relative clause

Tags: commas

Context: "When we didn’t like what we earned(,) and we couldn’t find a better opportunity, we simply moved to another state."

I'm not sure whether to add a comma here or not. Both clauses, "we didn't" and "we couldn't," refer to "when."

Comment: Personally I think *both* commas are "optional" here. Making it a stylistic choice / matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma before "and" does not belong here and adds an unnecessary pause/stumble to the sentence.

A comma like that would belong before "and" when the two clauses can each stand on their own as complete sentences. E.g.

> We didn't like what we earned, and we felt bad about our prospects.